# Store and call method from a HashMap

Tags: java, design-patterns, refactoring

I have 2 files: ImplementationProvider and CaseHandler.

ImplementationProvider:

```
class ImplementationProvider {
    public void method1(Object[] params) {}
    public void method2(Object[] params) {}
    ...
    public void method100(Object[] params) {}
}
```

CaseHandler:

```
class CaseHandler {
    ImplementationProvider ip; // auto injected
    public void handle(String s, String param) {
        switch(s) {
            case USE_CASE_ONE: ip.method1(param); break;
            case USE_CASE_TWO: ip.method2(param); break;
            ...
        }
    }   
}
```

How can I refactor the CaseHandler so that the USE_CASE strings are keys in a HashMap where the values would be the methods? The main issue I'm having is the propagation of the parameters. Other answers here recommend using an interface, however I need to provide the parameter on runtime.

Comment: What's the return type of your 100 methods? Should it be void?

Comment: @Eran They're all void for now (can't think of a use case at the moment where they wouldn't be)

Comment: What do you hope to gain by putting the methods in a hashmap? Do the bindings change at runtime? I'd tend to process s to be a valid method name and use reflection, if you have to code all the bindings then building the hashmap is probably less maintainable than a case statement.

Comment: @PeteKirkham less code inside the CaseHandler, O(1) search for the correct method.

Comment: Does your profiling show it's a bottleneck? Hashing a string requires processing all its characters and then you have an extra level of redirection. The switch doesn't have to do either ( depending on how good at optimising the compiler is, but IIRC the optimisation is only done for switch statements with many cases, as linear search that fits into the CPU cache is faster than hashing that results in a miss). The total amount of code is the greater if you have to set up a map.

Comment: @PeteKirkham on 89 cases I'm getting noticeable improvement as this operation is called VERY frequently (I do not have an official benchmark).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way I can think of, using the `Consumer` functional interface:

```
Map<String,Consumer<Object[]>> methods = new HashMap<>();

methods.put (USE_CASE_ONE, param -> ip.method1(param));
methods.put (USE_CASE_TWO, param -> ip.method2(param));
...

public void handle(String s, String param) {
    methods.get(s).accept(new Object[]{param});
}
```

EDIT:

If your methods require two parameters, you can use the `BiConsumer` interface:

```
Map<String,BiConsumer<String,List<String>>> methods = new HashMap<>();

methods.put (USE_CASE_ONE, (s,l) -> ip.method1(s,l));
methods.put (USE_CASE_TWO, (s,l) -> ip.method2(s,l));
...

public void handle(String s, String param) {
    methods.get(s).accept(someString,someListOfStrings);
}
```

Comment: In my concrete use-case, there're 2 parameters instead of only one (a String and a List<String>). What's the correct syntax to accept both parameters (or how do I generalize, because the method that I'm calling could require N parameters). Using Object[], the parameters are of type Object[] and <lambda parameter>.

map.put("USE_CASE_ONE", (param_one, param_two) -> ip.method1(param_one, param_two));

Comment: @i712345 if you require two parameters, use `BiConsumer<String,List<String>>` instead of `Consumer<Object[]>`.

Comment: aha, I understand the pattern now. So in general, It'd be better if I make a class that'll store my parameter data (since I do not know how many parameters I need) and then access the ones I need from an object?

Comment: You can use method references and shorten `param -> ip.method1(param)` to `ip::method1`.

Comment: @markusk that's true, but there are methods where the second parameter is unused.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Java 8, you can lever the `Consumer` functional interface to parametrize your map's values with.

Example:

```
private static Map<String, Consumer<String>> MAP = new HashMap<>();
static {
    MAP.put("USE_CASE_ONE", (s) -> {/*TODO something with param s*/});
    // etc.
}
```

... then somewhere else:

```
public void handle(String key, String param) {
        // TODO check key exists
        MAP.get(key).accept(param);
}
```

What happens here is that for each given key set entry, you map it with a function that consumes a `String` (your `param`).

Then, you invoke the `Consumer`'s `accept` on your given param in one line.